# How to perform DELETE operation on Northwind OData Service (SAPUI5)?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I implemented a SAPUI5 `List`, in which data from a public Northwind API is displayed.

```
var odataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("https://services.odata.org/V2/(S(c0...))/OData/OData.svc/");
odataModel.read("/Categories", {
    success: function (oData, oResponse) {
        MessageBox.success("Success");

    },
    error: function (oError) {
        MessageBox.error("Error");
    }
});
this.getView().setModel(odataModel);
```

This works and I can see the three categories with their ID from Northwind API. Now I tried implementing not only the READ but also the rest of the four CRUD operations. In all four functions I've used, I receive the same error, f.ex. while trying to delete an entry: `Request failed with status code 400: DELETE Categories(2) - "code":"","message":"'id-1677075...' is not a valid value for the 'Content-ID' header. In batch requests, the 'Content-ID' header must be an integer value."`
Unfortunately I've no idea what is meant by Content-ID and since I couldn't find anything helpful online, I'm writing this ticket here.

Delete function:

```
deleteData: function () {
    var list = this.getView().byId("list");
    var selItem = list.getSelectedItem();
    var title = selItem.getTitle();
    var path = "/Categories(" + title + ")"; ///Categories(2);
    var odataModel = this.getView().getModel();

    odataModel.remove(path, {
        success: function (data, response) {
            MessageBox.success("Deleted data");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            MessageBox.error("Deletion failed");
        }
    })
}
```

Code from: https://blogs.sap.com/2021/02/23/crud-operations-on-odata-services-using-different-techniques.-1./

EDIT: Code of Update function:

```
updateData: function () {
    var list = this.getView().byId("list");
    var selItem = list.getSelectedItem();
    var title = selItem.getTitle();

    // ID, Name from two Input fields
    var ID = this.getView().byId("idinput").getValue();
    var Name = this.getView().byId("nameinput").getValue();

    // Setting up payload
    var payload = {
        ID: parseInt(ID),
        Name: Name
    };

    // Defining path where to perform update
    var path = "/Categories(" + title + ")";
    var odataModel = this.getView().getModel();
    this.getView().getModel().setUseBatch(false);

    // Request update
    odataModel.update(path, payload, {
        success: function (data, response) {
            MessageBox.success("Successfully Updated");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            MessageBox.error("Error while updating the data");
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Try to set the batch mode to false before the request.
You can do that with the following command: `this.getView().getModel().setUseBatch(false);`

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment @JulianSchmuckli - It worked! Could you please explain what you did there, I'd then accept your answer for you getting the deserved reputation. But I have one follow-up question: The update function still does not work, I can only update the Name but not the ID, does this have something to do with your code snippet? (I'm going to put the code of the update function in my ticket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can try to disable the batch usage in the SAPUI5 framework for your default model by simply adding this command before the requests.

```js
this.getView().getModel().setUseBatch(false);
```

The batch requesting in OData seems to be not correctly implemented in the Northwind service somehow.

With this command, you disable this batch mode and start creating normal HTTP requests. These are also directly visible in the network panel in the developer settings of your browser.

To your follow up question:

Well, it looks like that the ID is a key, and you cannot change a key in OData with an Update request, since it could have dependencies to other entities.
[image: Category entity]